# Django - Development server alternatives

Tags: django

Is there good alternatives to the django developement server (runserver) that are more performant,
especially in concurency and static serving, and that have the auto-reload function, without having to setup a full blown production environment ?

Im working on Windows so gunicorn cannot be used.

Comment: gunicorn doesn't work in windows? damn I thought it worked in windows as well :s. anyway, `rungevent` never threw me errors in -at least- windows 7, even when libevent works better in linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install and use the `rungevent` commant. It has auto-reload function and it's more performant than thread-based servers (it is greenlet-oriented). The only caveat is the static file serving: you must install a webserver or proxy like nginx for that.

Are you doing so high bulk tests in ur dev server so you suffer this -specially regarding static files-? If so, then you must emulate, as said, a productive environment (just have an nginx correctly configured pointing to the address:port you use for your `rungevent` command).

If static files is not your problem, install a `rungevent` command and try how it works.

Comment: Correct, but he already said not having a production environment, if you start configuring nginx, static serving etc, there is no point for not going sem production-like (which I believe is the best way to be sure about everything). Not that your answer is wrong...just my opinion in terms of the question asked.

Comment: Under normal conditions you're right, but there's no easy and performant way to serve static files quicly without prod-like setting of nginx.

Additional scenarios where you must setup a prod-like environment in your local computer with nginx are: facebook application - even mounted locally (it requires HTTPS); websockets (realtime) application.

However, this has still a long distance before becoming the setup of a production environment: you must deal with cache, with websockets timeout (in the sample I gave), with cross-origin requests, ... having a simple nginx is not enough to be prodlike

Comment: I totally agree with you, most of the times (project depending) I work on a semi production setup, just to make sure that everything is setup as it should be, I just break down settings to dev and prod which I can really fast switch between. As I said you answer (for my likes) is the way to go :)

Answer (score 2):

No since dev sites are made to handle limited requests, runserver runs fine on a machine that can match the requirements of your app.
If you are dealing with a large scale dev project which your system cannot tolerate, then it's either time to reproduce a production environment or upgrade.
I find it difficult to believe that your application is that bad in terms of performance, again if you are trying to test the behavior of a full production site (in terms of DB entries etc) then its time to emulate the production environment.
If that is not the case, then I would start checking the underlying models / code of the project.

Comment: I agree with you. I am working on a cartographic app that serves a lot of tiles. Each tile is a request so threading could enhance testing even in dev.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you don't want to use django dev server you will have to spend some time to setup anyway. But the good part is that you can do it only once. Sequential deploying will take very little time.

Not so much time ago I switched from fastcgi to uWSGI and it made my life much easier.
uWSGI is awesome! It has autoreload (which works both in daemon mode and when launched directly in terminal). When launched in terminal you can use debugger (e.g. `pdb`) during request just like you do in django dev-server. And of course you can debug with `print` in simple cases.

I'm using it with nginx which serves both static and uWSGI but it of course can be any server.
The most useful feature for me in this configuration is that you use the same thing both for dev and production. For simple projects after developing you just turn off autoreload and a few other options and it's ready.